# Typescript inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript

I have some questions about typescript/javascript inheritance. I have the following base class (express controller router):

```
abstract class BaseCtrl {
  abstract model;

  // Get all
  getAll = (req, res) => {
    this.model.find({}, (err, docs) => {
      if (err) { return console.error(err); }
      res.json(docs);
    });
  };
export default BaseCtrl;
```

And the following class that implements that base:

```
import BaseCtrl from './base';
import Card from '../models/card';

export default class CardCtrl extends BaseCtrl {
  model = Card;

  getAll = (req, res) => {
    super.getAll(req, res);
  }

}
```

This code gives me the error:

> Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the super keyword

I would like to know how to call the super method. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Working DEMO**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20BaseCtrl%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20model%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Get%20all%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getAll%20(req%2C%20res)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.model.find(%7B%7D%2C%20(err%2C%20docs)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(err)%20%7B%20return%20console.error(err)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20res.json(docs)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20CardCtrl%20extends%20BaseCtrl%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20model%20%3D%20'Card'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20getAll%20(req%2C%20res)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super.getAll(req%2C%20res)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D)

You're defining `getAll` as a member property but you need to define it as a normal member method

Typescript overriding features works properly with member methods and not properties.

```
abstract class BaseCtrl {
    abstract model;    
    // Get all
    getAll (req, res) {
        this.model.find({}, (err, docs) => {
            if (err) { return console.error(err); }
            res.json(docs);
        });
    };
}

export class CardCtrl extends BaseCtrl {   
  getAll (req, res) {
    super.getAll(req, res);
  }

}
```

Propably, you may need to use `getAll` as a reference when passing to the router,So you may need to bind the scope like this `cardCtrl.getAll.bind(cardCtrl);`

Comment: Hi Mouneer. Have you ever faced the problem that "this" is undefined in the base class, using this code? I'm getting this error and I don't know why!

Comment: check my edit. Instead of using it as `cardCtrl.getAll` bind the scope. Got it?

Comment: Great! Thank you so much Mouneer! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `getAll` as a proper method:

```
abstract class BaseCtrl {
    abstract model;

    // Get all
    getAll(req, res) {
        this.model.find({}, (err, docs) => {
            if (err) { return console.error(err); }
            res.json(docs);
        });
    }
};
export default BaseCtrl;
```

Then, you can override it:

```
import BaseCtrl from './base';
import Card from '../models/card';

export default class CardCtrl extends BaseCtrl {
     model = Card;

     getAll(req, res) {
       super.getAll(req, res);
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matias! Thanks for you answer! Do you know how can I get this code working with the routes.route:

router.route('/cards').get(passport.authenticate('login', {session: false}), cardCtrl.getAll);

If I transform like you said, this code gets broken, because getAll is not more a property with function.